# How to completely reset service worker cache only having access to the service worker code, as the rest is cached and not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Some of my users are experiencing issues with the page not loading correctly, i don't have ways to debug it but i feel like it might be because the html file was cached by the service worker while the js wasn't, so when the html tries to load the page, it doesn't manage to as the files were removed. The app is a cache first loaded app, i wanted to reset this cache and refresh tabs to maybe hope to fix it, currently i added this so that if there is breaking changes in the future it can wipe all the service worker data:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', async (event) => {
    //If there is a major version, skip waiting and refresh all tabs
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys()
    if(!cacheKeys.length) return console.log("Fresh install")
    const appKeys = cacheKeys.filter(e => e.includes(APP_NAME))
    if(!appKeys.length) return console.log("Fresh install")
    const majorVersionKeys = appKeys.filter(e => e.startsWith(`${MAJOR_VERSION}`))
    if(majorVersionKeys.length === 0) { //there are existing cache keys but 
        console.log("Major version change, skipping waiting and refreshing all tabs")
        self.skipWaiting()
        self.clients.claim()
        self.clients.matchAll({type: "window"}).then(clients => {
            clients.forEach(client => {
                client.navigate(client.url)
            })
        })
    }
})
```

i'm worried the `install` event runs only when there is a `window.navigator.serviceWorker.register` but being broken, the js file will never be able to be opened, how could i do it?

I'm also a bit confused as of how this could have happened and i'm not sure how i could fix the underlaying issue as during my testing i didn't find any issuse. I rewrote my app going from react to next.js, the issue is in this [website](https://specy.github.io/skyMusic/), my main concern is resetting the cache without being able to access the js, but if someone has any other suggestions, let me know